# My TouchPad is not responding on an Acer Aspire E1-471-6650

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, acer, synaptics

I recently bought an Acer Aspire E1-471-6650 and I already have problems. First, when I tried to use the touchpad on a LiveCD, it wasn't responding. When I installed it in my notebook, it wasn't responding either. I was browsing for solutions and I couldn't find a solution for it.
When I write `xinput` command:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2     [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer           id=4     [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad           id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Optical Mouse                        id=11    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3     [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard          id=5     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                         id=6     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                            id=7     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                         id=8     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                         id=9     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                            id=10    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard         id=12    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                     id=14    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

with `dpkg -l xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

```
Nombre: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
Versión :1.6.2-1ubuntu5          
Arquitectura:   i386    
Descripción: Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
```

with `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
...
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event9
B: PROP=9
B: EV=b
B: KEY=6420 0 30000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2608000 11000003
...
```

I tested these solutions:

I was able to enable/disable this with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

I wrote in final of paragraph of `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "touchpad catchall"
   Driver "synaptics"
   MatchIsTouchpad "on"
   Option "TapButton1" "1"
   Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"
EndSection
```

Can somebody help me? .. thanks!

Comment: Oh man .. I've had this problem forever and the control / function / F7 worked like a charm .. thank you .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You might try enabling the touchpad with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. I had to do this with my Acer Aspire E431.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue I tried this still no luck ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111236 – Lohith MV Sep 3 '14 at 18:24

Somehow it got fixed. I just did the regular Ubuntu update on my laptop today which i do everyday and voila it got fixed after the restart. It seems Ubuntu people were working on this problem and they have released a fix.